# Single command for git commit/rebase/squash

Tags: git

I often perform the following pattern:

1. `git commit -am "well formatted message"`
2. Make another small change (something I forgot)
3. `git commit -am "foo"`
4. `git rebase -i` (and squash the `foo` commit)
5. Edit the commit message, to remove "foo"

Can I perform steps 3 to 5 with a single command or script? i.e. commit all and add to previous commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before I supply the answer below, note that `git commit` has an option, `--amend`, that (in effect):

- does a soft reset to move back one commit, then
- does the commit you want

which effectively replaces the commit with the fixed-up one.  (The "in effect" is because it handles merges correctly.)  For instance:

```
$ git commit -am "well formatted message"
```

Now the commit graph looks like this:

```
o - o - A    <-- HEAD=yourbranch
```

and you realize you forgot something, so you fix it and use:

```
$ git commit -a --amend --no-edit
```

(the `--no-edit` avoids bringing up the editor).  Git effectively backs up one commit and makes a new commit `A'`:

```
        A   [abandoned, can only be found in reflog]
      /
o - o - A'  <-- HEAD=yourbranch
```

This is usually the tool you need here.  But it doesn't work if you've made a second "good" commit and need to fix something further back in history.  For that, read on.

---

Since git version 1.7.0 (but with some fixes up through 1.8.4, so best to do this in 1.8.4 or later), `git rebase` has had an option spelled `--autosquash`.  The `git commit` command has `--fixup=` and `--squash=` options that work with this, and `git rebase` has a configuration item, `rebase.autoSquash`, that turns on `--autosquash` by default, so that you don't have to specify it every time.

This *is* described in [the `git rebase` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html), but it's a bit obscure:

> ```
>    --autosquash, --no-autosquash
>        When the commit log message begins with "squash! ..." (or "fixup!
>        ..."), and there is a commit whose title begins with the same ...,
>        automatically modify the todo list of rebase -i so that the commit
>        marked for squashing comes right after the commit to be modified,
>        and change the action of the moved commit from pick to squash (or
>        fixup). Ignores subsequent "fixup! " or "squash! " after the first,
>        in case you referred to an earlier fixup/squash with git commit
>        --fixup/--squash.
> ```

```
       This option is only valid when the --interactive option is used.
```

The way it works is pretty simple, and I think it makes more sense once you see how it works.  The interactive rebase script (it's a shell script, which makes it easy to see how it does this, if you want to look at the details) starts by collecting up the list of commits, along with their subject-lines in the commit message.  This is the exactly the same as the stuff you see in `git log --oneline` output (here's a snippet from the git tree for git):

```
88d5072 am --skip: revert changes introduced by failed 3way merge
19bf6c9 fsck: report errors if reflog entries point at invalid objects
d66ae59 fsck_handle_reflog_sha1(): new function
```

Suppose that after `88d5072`, we had a line that read:

```
1234567 fixup! fsck_handle_reflog_sha1(): new function
```

This would be a commit made after `d66ae59` (because it's higher up in the log output); its subject line exactly matches that of `d66ae59`, except for the word "fixup" in front (and the exclamation point and space).

What the `rebase` script *does* with this is to shuffle the commits around a bit so that the `fixup!` commit comes right after the original commit, and where it would normally say `pick`, say `fixup`.  Then, as it processes through the commits, it applies the original commit as usual, and applies the fixup as a fixup, just as if you had moved the commit in your list of commits and changed `pick` to `fixup`.

In short, it simply edits the rebase "to do" list automatically for you.  You'll see the fixup when the interactive rebase edit session starts.

When you use `git commit` with `--fixup=<...>`, git makes the commit message read the right way to work with `--autosquash`.  You must do this at the time of the commit, rather than at the time of the rebase.

Hence, let's say that instead of the original scenario (for which `git commit --amend` works well), you did this:

```
... edit ...
git commit ... # make slightly flawed commit A
... edit ...
git commit ... # make good commit B
... realize that there's a flaw in A; edit ...
$ git commit -a --fixup=HEAD^
```

This gives you a three-commit series:

```
o - o - A - B - C   <-- HEAD=yourbranch
```

where commit `C` is just the fix for `A`.  If you run `git log --oneline` you'll see it has the form that `git rebase --autosquash` likes; so now when you run `git rebase -i --autosquash`, your TODO list will have:

```
pick 1234567   well formatted message
fixup 3333333  fixup! well formatted message
pick fedcba9   another well formatted message
```

and you can simply exit the editor and you'll get what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

[torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32365946/1228454) explains this in a lot of detail, and I would like to add a practical piece of advice that I use on a daily basis to make this even simpler.

I use an alias that does what Torek describes - it adds whatever changes you've made to the previous commit, including the same commit message. Here's the alias (defined in `~/.bash_profile` or similar):

```
alias gcaa='git commit -a --amend -C HEAD'
```

In your example, I would use it like this:

1. `git commit -am "well formatted message"`
2. Make another small change (something I forgot)
3. `gcaa`

Keep the usual recommendations when amending commits in mind: Only do this if you have not pushed the first commit. The `amend` option is creating a new commit, it's changing the history. If you have already pushed the first commit and then amend it, it will change the repositories history, and you will have to `force` the next push, with potential impact for other users of the repo who have already pulled your first commit. Keep that in mind and you should be good.